# On the SIM800, what is the difference between the "at+sapbr" commands, and "at+cstt", "at+ciicr" etc?

Tags: gprs, sim800

I understand that *"at+sapbr"* is used for setting up an HTTP or FTP connection and that *"at+cstt"* , *"at+ciicr"* etc. are used for just a TCP connection.

However, from what I understand, HTTP/FTP are just a layers on top of the TCP protocol. 
Why doesn't the SIM800 use *"at+sapbr"* for everything? Is there a difference in the way the SIM800 sets up the connection?

I tried different searches on Google, but I can't find a clear answer.